# copying one column to another on same table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to copy the values in products_description_second to the same column where the language_id = 3 so I so far have:

```
UPDATE pd1 SET
     pd1.products_description_second = pd2.products_description_second
from products_description pd1 
    join products_description pd2 on pd1.products_id = pd2.products_id and  pd2.language_id = 3
WHERE pd2.language_id = 1
```

I am however getting a syntax error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from products_description pd1 join products_description pd2 on pd1.product' at line 3
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You cant use from in update query, and you should use `set` after all `joins`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct. This should work

```
UPDATE products_description pd1  
JOIN products_description pd2 on pd1.products_id = pd2.products_id and pd2.language_id = 3
SET pd1.products_description_second = pd2.products_description_second
WHERE pd2.language_id = 1
```

Comment: hmm thanks no error but I am getting 0 rows affected.. must be doing something wrong